# How to make a timer when screen is inactice show dialogbox?

Tags: flutter, timer, dialog

i try to make a timer which detect if the screen is not using then it will pop up a dialogbox. The popup working fine after 5sec but how can i make it only popup one times instead of every 5sec will popup a new dialog box?

```
timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (time) {
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
  print('Something');
  showDialog(

      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
        });
        return Dialog(

          child: _imageslideshowProductDetails(),
        );
      }).then((value){
    timer?.cancel();
});});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
Timer.run(); // it will only run once and will pop after 5 secs
```

Comment: hi if i close the dialogbox, how to let the timer rerun again if the screen is not touching for 5sec ?

Comment: create Periodic Timer which will keep running every 5 seconds,

then you have to maintain a variable called bool didUserTouchedScreen = false;

and set didUserTouchedScreen to true whenever user touches the screen, now to detect is user touched the screen? wrap entire screen with gestureDetector and in onTap callback set didUserTouchedScreen as true,

so in every periodic callback check if didUserTouchedScreen is true then do your stuff,

if you want to close the timer after you execute your stuff then cancel timer before that